# configureCell is not triggered when I update a datasource using RxDatasources

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am having a behavior relay in my view model that is used as a source of data. Its defined like this:

```
var posts: BehaviorRelay<[PostModel]>
```

It is initialized with data through the network, and it initializes tableView normally when I bind data to it.

Now, if I try to change say, the like status of a post here, like this (this is also in my view model):

```
private func observeLikeStatusChange() {
        
        self.changedLikeStatusForPost
            .withLatestFrom(self.posts, resultSelector: { ($1, $0) })
            .map{ (posts, changedPost) -> [PostModel] in
                //...
                var editedPosts = posts
                editedPosts[index] = changedPost // here data is correct, index, changedContact
                return editedPosts
            }
            .bind(to: self.posts)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

So with this, nothing happens. If I remove the element from `editedPosts`, the `tableView` updates correctly and removes the row.

`PostModel` struct conforms to `Equatable`, and it requires all properties to be the same at the moment.

In my view controller, I create datasource like this:

```
tableView.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)
 let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<PostsSectionModel>(
            configureCell: { dataSource, tableView, indexPath, item in
             //...
                return postCell
            })
        
        postsViewModel.posts
            .map({ posts in
                let models = posts.map{ PostCellModel(model: $0) }
                return [PostsSectionModel(model: "", items: models)]
            }) // If I put debug() here, this is triggered and I get correct section model with correct values
            .bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

So, as I said, I am getting correct values, but configureCell is not triggered. What I am doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Here is PostCellModel:

import Foundation

```
import RxDataSources

typealias PostsSectionModel = AnimatableSectionModel<String, PostCellModel>


struct PostCellModel : Equatable, IdentifiableType {
    
    static func == (lhs: PostCellModel, rhs: PostCellModel) -> Bool {
        
        return lhs.model.id == rhs.model.id
    }
    
    var identity: Int {
        return model.id
    }
    var model: PostModel
}
```

and a PostModel:

```
 struct PostModel: Codable, CellDataModel, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: PostModel, rhs: PostModel) -> Bool {
       return
        lhs.liked == rhs.liked &&
        rhs.title == lhs.title &&
        
        lhs.location == rhs.location &&
        lhs.author == rhs.author &&
       
        lhs.created == rhs.created
    }
    
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let location: String?
    let author: String
    let created: Int
    let liked:Bool
}
```

Comment: How is `PostModel` and `PostsSectionModel` defined?

Comment: @DanielT. Hi, sorry for the late response. I added `PostModel` and `PostsSectionModel`. As well as `PostCellModel`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined your Equatable conformance incorrectly in the `PostCellModel`. Because of that, the system is unable to tell whether a cell model has changed... Remove your manually defined `==(lhs:rhs:)` and let the system generate them for you and you should be fine...

```
typealias PostsSectionModel = AnimatableSectionModel<String, PostCellModel>

struct PostCellModel : Equatable, IdentifiableType {
    var identity: Int {
        return model.id
    }
    var model: PostModel
}

struct PostModel: Codable, CellDataModel, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let location: String?
    let author: String
    let created: Int
    let liked:Bool
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked, here's some more about why... The underlying system uses the `==` to tell if two objects with the same `identity` are indeed different. If they aren't it won't replace them. Since your `==` only compared identities, the system didn't know that the model had changed value.